# How to start graph lines at 0 in the Y axis with Bokeh (Python)

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh for showing line graphs at my Django/Python web.

By default, the graphs start at the minimum value provided, but I want them to start always at 0 in the Y-axis.

For example, in the following example it starts at 167 in the Y-axis (the minimum value in that data set), but I wanted to start at 0.

[image: graph]

y_range seems to work fine if I want to define a minimum and a maximum, but I only want to define the minimum (0) and let the data "decide" the maximum.

I've tried using `y_range=(0, None)`, `min_border=0`, `start=0` and a bunch of other things, without success. ChatGPT keeps recommending me alternatives that don't really work or even exist.

This is my current code:

```
y = WHATEVER
x = WHATEVER  

plot = figure(title='TITLE', 
        x_axis_type='datetime',
        sizing_mode="stretch_width", 
        max_width=600, 
        height=400)

plot.line(x, y, line_width=4)
script, div = components(plot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ChatGPT keeps recommending me alternatives that don't really work or even exist.

This should not be surprising, ChatGPT is not a serious or reliable source of accurate information.

In any case, the only thing you need to do is set:

```
plot.y_range.start = 0
```

with the default range (i.e. don't pass a range value to `figure`). That will keep auto-ranging for the upper y-axis but pin the start to 0.

Comment: Thanks! It works. It is better to add that line in some specific place/order? Or it doesn't matter? I've added it in a new line before "plot.line ..."

Comment: Barring anything unusual, it should not matter where it goes.